# call a function to get states of different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Says I have component A parent component and a component B as the child component. I have a function of 'save' in the parent, but I also need the state of component B, how do I get the states of component B in the parent?

Note: The click handler of save is in the parent compoent.

I can pass the handleSave function in `<ComponentB handleSave={this.handleSave} />`but how can I get the form state of component B in the handleSave function?

Comment: This is so common a pattern in React that its commonly described as _Lifting State Up_. This pattern is documented in the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Perhaps it may be helpful for you

Comment: Well either you lift the state up or have the save button in the form component which triggeres the action in parent using the handler passed as props

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri the problem is the save button is in the parent. How can I pass a function to the children to get their states?

Answer (score 0):

> I can pass the handleSave function in `<ComponentB handleSave={this.handleSave} />`

by which you hand over control over the saving from `ComponentA` to `ComponentB`.

No, better implement some sort of change-handler

```
<ComponentB onChanged={(value) => {
  // do something with these values, like:
  this.setState({
    foo: value
  });
}} />
```

and just to clarify: `value` should most likely not be the complete `state` of `ComponentB` but really some representation of the data you want to propagate to the classes that use this Component.

> what if I want to avoid this render props pattern? can I do this instead? componentDidUpdate() { this.props.getStates(this.state) } in componentB? where getStates is a method passed from componentA

1st. this is no render props pattern, the passed method doesn't render anything.

2nd. I don't think `componentDidUpdate` is the right place for this; it might even result in kind of an infinite loop of the component being updated -> sending the value to the parent -> parent updating its state -> parent re-rendering -> component being updated -> ...

A better place would be the Event-listener in wich `setState` inside of `ComponentB`. This is the place where something about the data actually changes; the change you want to propagate to the parent.

3rd. again, don't pass `this.state`

- this limits you in your possibilities on what your state looks like/contains, because it now has to satisfy the other component as well
- this exposes the state-object so that the internal state of your component may be modified without react being notified -> Basically undercutting the main purpose of React (updating the view based on the changes to the state and the props)

pass some different object, and even if this is just `{...this.state}` to start with. It leaves you with all the options to change that.

And last:

> where getStates is a method passed from componentA

that's exactly what I did here, only that I called that method `onChanged` ;)

Comment: what if I want to avoid this render props pattern? can I do this instead? `componentDidUpdate() { this.props.getStates(this.state) }` in componentB? where `getStates` is a method passed from componentA.

Answer (score 0):

Inside ComponentB you could expose the state on the call:

```
 this.props.handleSave(this.state)
```

Then define it as:

```
handleSave(childState) {
 //...
}
```